# Android - crash without stacktrace when using support library rev 13

Tags: android, exception, revision, android-support-library

Recently I updated my android support library to the latest one - revision 13.
Since then, it began to crash when I opened an activity that uses ViewPager and Pager adapter along with Tabs. The weird issue is that when the crash happens, it just freezes instead of Force Closing. Then, I get this in the LogCat

```
06-06 11:45:33.828: D/AndroidRuntime(6371): Shutting down VM
06-06 11:45:33.828: W/dalvikvm(6371): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4114eac8)
```

Then that's it. Boom.
I don't know why it just shuts down VM and not print any stackTrace message after exception.
I think this exception is thrown because of the following changes they made in this revision.

**Updated ViewPager to throw an exception if the associated PagerAdapter class is modified without a call to notifyDataSetChanged().**

So, my question is, how can I know what kind of exception happened where, without stacktrace? Secondly, should I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` somewhere in my code? How?...

Comment: **"how can I know what kind of exception happened where"** - Make extensive use of `Log.d(...)` and track the log messages to point of it freezing then put try/catch around the next code. I log things like "Entering methodA()" and "Leaving methodA()" so I know exactly which method contains the problem.